# Error handling in async routing in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, axios

I have express routing below and it works. Hovewer, if axios couldn't retrieve any information due to error, I can't respond with res.send but I can see error log in terminal. How can I catch error? Ideally if it couldn't retrieve data it should respond 'Couldn't connect'.

```
router.get('/accounts', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${config.url}/accounts`, {
      auth: config.auth
    });
    const data = await response.data.results;
    res.json(data);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.send('Could not connect');
  }
});
```

Comment: Your snippet works. When there is an error with `axios` my client receives `Could not connect`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your catch block you are trying to parse a circular JSON object. I recommend using the [json-stringify-safe](https://github.com/moll/json-stringify-safe) library to solve your issue:

install json-stringify-safe:

```
    $ npm install json-stringify-safe --save
```

solution:

```
const express = require('express')
const axios = require('axios');
const app = express();
var stringify = require('json-stringify-safe');


app.get('/accounts', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('someInvalidUrl'); // will throw error
        return res.json(response);
    } catch (e) {
        e = JSON.parse(stringify(e)); // safely parse circular JSON object
        res.send(e); // will return error as json
    }
});
```